# Override Button's Height and Width Properties' TypeConverterAttribute in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, width, dependency-properties

I want to override default TypeConverterAttribute i.e. LengthConverter to my own created type converter class CustomLengthConverter in my WPF application.

I am doing the following:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{   
    [TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(CustomLengthConverter))]
    public new double Width
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Width;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Width = value;    
        }
    }
}
```

But when assigned a value to Width propoerty my overriden "ConvertFrom" is not called. It seems it still uses the default LengthConverter class for performing type conversion.

The purpose of doing it is that I want to add the support for additional measurement units in my application. Project demands that user can give a control's height and width in millimeters also which WPF does not support. So I need to use my convertor in case of the height and width are in millimeters.

Comment: Are Width and Height, dependency properties. I was just curious that this can be the reason that there behaviour is not being overriden.

Comment: @HighCore I want to add the units of measurements which Xaml processor supports. e.g. WPF control's hieghts and widths can only be in cm, px, pt and in. I need to add e.g. mm.